# Making a Julian calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I am a bit new to Java. I'm having some trouble writing a Calendar that accepts a year from the "Run Arguments" command. My instructor provided a class gives the weekday of the first day of January for a given year. If I understand correctly, we only need to know when January begins to know the weekday that the other months begin. I need some help with this because I was only able to do the first day of January for every month. Also, I would appreciate some help with bringing the days to a new line after they reach the last weekday. Thank you all in advance.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
public class JulianCalendar
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JulianDate JD = new JulianDate();
      int date = JD.toJulian(2018,1,1);
      int dayOfWeek = (date+1)%7;
      printCalendar();
   }
   public static void printCalendar()
   {
      JulianDate JD = new JulianDate();
      int date = JD.toJulian(2018,1,1);
      int dayOfWeek = (date+1)%7;
      int currentyear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
      for (int month=1; month <= 12; month++)
      {
         String monthString;
         //prints out months
         switch (month) 
         {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
          }
          System.out.printf("\n%17s\n",monthString);
          System.out.println("\nSun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
          System.out.print("  ");
          for(int i=0; i<dayOfWeek;i++)
          {
            System.out.print("    ");
          }
          int days=0;
          switch (month)
          {
            case 1:  days = 31;
                     break;
            case 2:  days = 28;
                     break;
            case 3:  days = 31;
                     break;
            case 4:  days = 30;
                     break;
            case 5:  days = 31;
                     break;
            case 6:  days = 30;
                     break;
            case 7:  days = 31;
                     break;
            case 8:  days = 31;
                     break;
            case 9:  days = 30;
                     break;
            case 10: days = 31;
                     break;
            case 11: days = 30;
                     break;
            case 12: days = 31;
                     break;
          }
          for (int i=1; i<=days; i++)
          {
            System.out.printf("%-4d",i);
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How does the output look like? How should it look like? Add an example.

Comment: Hard to understand, maybe `public static void printCalendar(int year) {  . . . int date = JD.toJulian(year,1,1);` ? or are you just needing a `System.out.println();` to *jump* to next line ?

Comment: @MrSmith42 Sorry about that. Here is an image I screened of an example. February has lines around it indicating it is the current month. https://ibb.co/b3Oyqn

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Hi Carlos. When I'm trying to put the days on a new line at the end of the week, I heard I can use a column counter. Since there are always 7 days of the week, do you think I can say go to a new line at the 7th column? I'm not sure how I would code this column counter though.. Thanks